# Reading latest in spark kafka streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I wish to read only latest msg in spark streaming using kafka, but it also fetches past data

How to set auto.offset.reset in KafkaUtil for spark

```
JavaPairReceiverInputDStream<String, String> messages =
            KafkaUtils.createStream(jssc, args[0], args[1], topicMap);
```

how to set the conf to fetching only current message . Please give some example.

Thanks in advance, there is also another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546674/merging-two-streams-in-spark-streaming)

But not sufficient, pls help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use this method from KafkaUtils object:

```
 def createStream[K, V, U <: Decoder[_], T <: Decoder[_]](
      jssc: JavaStreamingContext,
      keyTypeClass: Class[K],
      valueTypeClass: Class[V],
      keyDecoderClass: Class[U],
      valueDecoderClass: Class[T],
      kafkaParams: JMap[String, String],
      topics: JMap[String, JInt],
      storageLevel: StorageLevel
    )
```

Depending on the Spark version, you cannot use java. There is a [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2103).

If you are using Spark 1.1.0, you need to add into **kafkaParams** parameter this property:

> "auto.offset.reset", "largest"

Another workaround is generate a **groupId** prefix randomly, but this is crappy.